# Como criar um menu scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Como é feito este menu fixo no topo da página que quando o usuário rola a tela para baixo ao chegar em um determinado local da página o menu diminui ficando compacto. E ao voltar a tela para cima o menu volta para a estilização inicial? Isto pode ser feito com a logo também?

Exemplo retirado do Website: https://builtwith.com/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fixar o menu estou usando

```html
position: fixed;
```

Porém, não sei como está sendo realizado este efeito se é Javascript ou css.

Usando as **informações obtidas aqui** eu conseguir fazer a barra de menu ter uma animação, entretanto a animação só se aplica aos menus, mas não é bem isto que eu quero e que as respostas abaixo propuseram. Eu quero ter este efeito "animação" na minha logo também. Alguém poderia poderia me ajudar?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav a {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav .navbar-toggle {
  margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


}
nav.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}
nav.shrink a {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  font-size: 15px;
}
nav.shrink .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 25px;
}
nav.shrink .navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
}
*Position logo*/ .navbar-brand img {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://d2z0lf9itclnw8.cloudfront.net/img/logo/navLogoENG@2x.png" width="250px" class="img-responsive" alt="">

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Pra fazer esse efeito, utiliza-se Javascript e CSS. Esse exemplo acho que é o que você quer: [Header Resize](http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll).

Comment: Estou olhando aqui Douglas. Eu fiz varias pesquisas no google, porém eu não sabia o nome para produzir isto efeito ai tive que vir aqui perguntar.

Comment: É isto mesmo Douglas que estava procurando se puder formular a sua resposta vou dar um upvote.

Comment: Olá amigo veja no link a opção na pratica com bootstrap do efeito que você deseja espero que agregue para formular seu projeto !
[Método em bootstrap](http://www.bootply.com/zsfX1yszuz)

Comment: @Rblima Este exemplo é basicamente o que meu código acima CSS e JavaScript faz, porém  não obtive o resultado desejado até o momento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da forma que costumo fazer é aplicar uma classe ao menu após a rolagem. A partir da classe é só estilizar seus elementos da forma que você quer. Nesse exemplo que estou enviando, animei apenas o `max-height` do "menu" que neste caso é apenas uma barra. Mas acredito que está bastante claro o que foi feito.

```js
$(function() {
  //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
  var header = $(".menu");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
      header.addClass("menuScroll");
    } else {
      header.removeClass("menuScroll");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu.menuScroll {
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">

</div>
```

Comment: Entendi como funciona @Leon Freire inclusive já implementei em meu layout usando Bootstrap, porém estou com problema na logo. adicionei .img-responsive para  ter o efeito também, mas não obtive o resultado esperado.

Comment: @RenatoLazaro Nesse caso eu precisaria ver o seu CSS para ver o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @Douglas Garrido Caro atualizei a minha pergunta com o que eu conseguir até o momento.

Comment: Caro atualizei a minha pergunta com o que eu conseguir até o momento.

Comment: @RenatoLazaro Basta você aplicar um tamanho para o logo dentro do seu menu após a redução. Tente algo como `.shrink img.img-responsive { width: 100px; }`