# Duvida barra de menu para sitre

Tags: php, javascript, html5, css3

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema, preciso fazer uma barra de menu em um site, e quando rolar a pagina a logo e o menu diminuem, igual nesse site do link abaixo.

https://www.grupoqueirozgalvao.com.br/

Alguém poderia me ajudar ???

Comment: Olá Roberto! Já procuraste aqui no site por respostas a perguntas idênticas?

Comment: Neste link tem um exemplo, veja no código fonte como é feito :) http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-create-a-resizing-menu-bar/

Comment: Olha [outro link aqui no proprio SOPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195306/como-criar-um-menu-scrolling)